# Should Slick DatabaseConfig and TableQuery values be shared & reused across threads & requests

Tags: multithreading, slick

I am using [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) (v3.1 currently).  I create my [`DatabaseConfig`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/database.html) from TypesafeConfig, and [`TableQuery`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/schemas.html) values for my schemas.

Which of these things should I be sharing across:

1. Requests
2. Threads

It's not clear to me from reading the docs.

---

Here's my own attempt at answering.

I observe that the `DatabaseConfig` (or some part of it) owns a connection pool.  So it seems pretty obvious that it's best to share this object across all requests and threads (treat it like a singleton).

For the `TableQuery` values, I have less insight.  I haven't done extensive testing but I don't see a particular reason I need to share these either over multiple requests or between my threads.